# How to read particular value from a segement in EDI file?

Tags: java, edi

For example, below is the data from my EDI file:

```
    ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*FOUNDTHISORG *ZZ*PLUS05931283*160411*1551*^*00501*111512123*0*P*:~
    GS*BE*FOUNDTHISORG*PLUS*20160411*1551*111512123*X*005010X220A1~
    ST*834*111512124*005010X220A1~
    BGN*00*111512123*20160411*1551*PT***4~
    REF*38*5931283~
    DTP*382*D8*20160411~
    N1*P5*FOUNDTHISORG*FI*13-5581829~
    N1*IN*Plus*FI*13-5581829~
    INS*Y*18*030*XN*A***RT~
    REF*0F*094282627~
    REF*1L*593128300010002~
    DTP*336*D8*19670605~
    DTP*286*D8*19900331~
    NM1*IL*1*Fname*Lname*H***34*094282627~
    PER*IP**HP*6317444093~
    N3*587 Some Drive~
    N4*Ridge*NY*11961~
    DMG*D8*19350319*F*R~
    HD*030**DEN**IND~
    DTP*348*D8*20160101~
    INS*Y*18*030*XN*A***RT~
    REF*0F*089307096~
    REF*1L*593128300010002~
    DTP*336*D8*19630917~
    DTP*286*D8*19950201~
    NM1*IL*1*Sname*Rname*A***34*089307096~
    PER*IP**HP*7184283161~
    N3*249-36 51st Avenue~
    N4*long Neck*NY*11362~
    DMG*D8*19390114*F*I~
    HD*030**DEN**IND~
    DTP*348*D8*20160101~
    INS*Y*18*030*XN*A***RT~
```

Now I need values of REF *0F* segment. Can you please write or suggest me a java code to read all the values in that segment. THere are about 600 segments like these and I need to read all of them and store them in a List or an Array.

Comment: Do you want any other information, or do you just want to take data from the lines that match the pattern "REF\\*OF[\d]+~"

Comment: in edi file it is zero-capital-F, not capital-O capital-F.

Comment: Use a translator.  Just because you could parse this in Java, doesn't mean you should.  A translator will handle syntax checking, 997 generation, scale out to different sources, communications, etc.  Stop reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You should use a library, such as `EDIReader`. It's implemented like a SAX parser.

Comment: Thank you all. I've written below code for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and wrote the code for my requirement. below is the code:

```
package com.FileOperations;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EDIRead {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        String path = "D:/FIleIO/fordfnd_elig.26448.txt";

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(path));
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            if(line.equals("eof"))
                break;
            if (line.startsWith("REF*0F")) {
                line = line.substring(line.indexOf("0F*")+3);
                line = line.replaceAll("~", "");
                list.add(line);
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
        System.err.println("Completed Parsing, here is the list of entries : ");
        for(String line : list){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

My sincere apologies if you felt that my question wasn't clear. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not EDI-safe.  The line terminator is the character found at the 102nd column of the `ISA` segment. The line breaks that follow are optional and are used for readability much like the line break between `XML` tags.